Timed 24 VDC automatic gate rams
I have a some electronic gate rams that are 24vdc. The customer has an access control system that sends a pulse to the ram controls to open, they time out and shut again. The client is wanting the gates to stay open when the access control is first activated between 6am - 6pm. Then at 6pm they want the gates to shut automatically and then the pulse of the access control sends a signal to open and close the gate as normal with it self opening and closing again until 6am the following day. So the gate stays open when the first signal is sent during the opening hours but opens and closes automatically by fob during the closed hours.
I know the best bet is a time clock but it is how to get it to stay on only when it receives its first signal from the access control. Basically so if its shut at Christmas the gate doesn't just open on its timer but it has signal sent to open it.

Just use a micro attached to a relay with an RTC and code up the conditions.

@VoltageSpike: Don't! Use a PLC so that you have support in twenty years' time and you have a robust solution.

Use a micro PLC.
These are available from all the major vendors: A-B, Siemens, Mitsubishi, etc.

They're typically 71.5 mm wide DIN rail mounting modules.
They're available in 24 V versions.
They're quite straightforward to program with combinational logic and timers.
Some, such as the Siemens LOGO! have real-time clocks and calendar functions (which would sort out your Christmas problem).
They're tough! They're designed for industrial environments.
They have keypad and LCD so there's a built-in HMI.
They're cheap.
Most importantly - anyone else can fix it when you're not around.

Most will offer a crippled version of the software to allow program development and simulations. Have a look for the Siemens LOGOsoft free version at https://www.siemens.com/global/en/products/automation/systems/industrial/plc/logo/logo-software.html.
